# How to map nested collection to class instance object in TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular application and need map nested object with collection. I have map first half of data but I am struggling to map collection, reference options[] under heading mapping Code

I have add question base class followed by DropdownQuestion class to which I am intended to map json data. structure of json data is in data model class

### data model class

```
export class QuestionsDataModel
{
  consultationId: string;
  displayId: string;
  displayOrder: string;
  questionId: string;
  questionType: string;
  title: string;
  questionElement: {
    questionElementId: string;
    questionElementTypeId: string;
    questionId: string;
    questionElementType: {
        id:string;
        typeDefination: string;
        validation: string;
    };
    preDefineAnswer:{
        questionElementId:string;
        preDefineAnswerId:string;
        text:string;
        preDefineSubAnswer:{
            preDefineAnswerId: string;
            preDefineSubAnswerId: string;
            subText:string;
        };
     };
   }  ;
 }
```

### Mapping code (need help here)

```
 for(var key in questionsList)
 {
   let _dropBox = new DropdownQuestion({
      consultationId: questionsList[key].consultationId,
      questionId: questionsList[key].questionId,
      questionElementId: questionsList[key].questionElementId,          
      questionType: questionsList[key].questionType,
      title:questionsList[key].title,
      key: questionsList[key].questionId,    
      label: questionsList[key].title,

      options: [  // need help here, how to map this collection from json data
        {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
        {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
        {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
        {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
      ],
      order: 1
    });
```

### Dropdown class

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

 export class DropdownQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
 controlType = 'dropdown';
 options: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];

 constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
   this.options = options['options'] || [];
 }
 }
```

### Question Base class

```
export class QuestionBase<T>{
consultationId: string;
questionId: string;
questionElementId:string;
questionType:string;
title:string;
value: T;
key: string;
label: string;
required: boolean;
order: number;
controlType: string;


constructor(options: {
    consultationId?:string,
    questionId?:string,
    questionElementId?:string,
    questionType?:string,
    title?:string,
    value?: T,
    key?: string,
    label?: string,
    required?: boolean,
    order?: number,
    controlType?: string
  } = {}) {
  this.consultationId = options.consultationId,
  this.questionId = options.questionId,
  this.questionElementId = options.questionElementId,
  this.questionType = options.questionType,
  this.title = options.title,
  this.value = options.value;
  this.key = options.key || '';
  this.label = options.label || '';
  this.required = !!options.required;
  this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
  this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
  }
}
```

[image]

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

### error after using map

[image]

Comment: I don't get what you try to achieve. The options parameter of your `QuestionBase` doesn't expect an `options` member. And what do you want to map to `options` ?

Comment: I need to assign nested collection from json to options which is 'preDefineAnswer' from data model

Comment: I need to replace options: [  
        {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
        {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
        {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
        {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
      ] with preDefineAnswer collections in loop, as you see this part is hard code for testing purpose, but I got data coming in json source which collection

Comment: I really need help here, let me know if it clear enough .. thanks

Comment: And what would be the mapping logic? Which member from preDefineAnswer is supposed to be the key, which one the value? How do you want to split one object into a collection?

Comment: I have just upload screen of data source at bottom of my question, key = preDefineAnswerId and value = text

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.prototype.map` function:

```
for(var key in questionsList)
{
 let _dropBox = new DropdownQuestion({
   [...],
   options: questionsList[key].preDefineAnswer.map(a => {key: a.preDefineAnswerId, value: a.text},
   [...]
 });
```

Comment: I am getting unused label for key and value

Comment: I have upload screen shot of error at bottom of my question , error after using map